Visual Studio Docker orchestrator: cannot debug when dockerfile isn't in project directory
Visual Studio does not show a debug option when using a Docker compose project (.dcproj) and the Dockerfile is not in the project folder but up a couple of levels.
I have the following existing file structure:
root
|- docker-compose.yml
|- docker-compose.dcproj
|-- DockerFiles\
|   |- Dockerfile
|-- TestForDocker\
|   |- TestForDocker.sln
|   |-- TestForDocker\
|       |- TestForDocker.csproj

This causes that there's not an StartDebugging option in the "Manage Docker Compose Launch Settings"

Placing the Dockerfile in the .csproj directory and changing the path in the docker-compose.yml makes the option to StartDebugging visible:

How can I have it so that the Dockerfile doesn't have to be in the same folder as the .csproj?
I've tried to add
<DockerfileFile>..\..\DockerFiles\Dockerfile</DockerfileFile>

to the .csproj, but to no avail, this especially in combination with
<DockerComposeProjectPath>..\..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>

For reference, here's the docker-compose.yml:
services:
  testfordocker:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}testfordocker
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerFiles/Dockerfile
# The StartDebugging becomes visible whith the line below uncommented instead of the one above.
#      dockerfile: TestForDocker/TestForDocker/Dockerfile


It is possible to add a label to your docker-compose.yml or docker-compose.override.yml to associate the service with the project.
build: 
  blah..blah
labels:
  com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name: "TestforDocker"

See Issue on github.
The label com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name unfortunately isn't defined in the online documentation.
Credits go to dbreshears on github

Unfortunately there is no direct possibility, but there is solution for debugging. You have the start the docker project without debugging, and after attach the Visual Studio Debugger for the running container(s).
There is to solution for this:

Type 'Containers' in the visual studio search box

Open the 'Containers' window
On the left side select the container which you want to debug
Select 'Attach to process' options

In the opening window, select the container again
At the bottom left, select 'Managed (.NET Core for Unix) code'
Hit the Attach button and wait couple of second

Not you are in debugger mode!

The other solution:

Select the Visual Studio top menu Debug/Attach to process menu
Choose Docker Linux container or Docker Windows container in the Connection type combo box.
Hit the 'Find' button Next to connection target

Select 'Local Machine' in the opened window
Find your container in the list, the select it

And follow the 6,7,8 step from previous solution.

There is possibility to attach more the one container, just repeat the steps above. This solution has advantages and disadvantages compared to the docker compose start.
Pro

Much faster start when you have a big solutions
If you have a big cluster (20 or more containers) a docker compose basically stop working because of the lot of memory usage

Cons

You have to select the container manually, each time.
If one container calling the other container, you have to attach this container too, to hit the breakpoint.

I hope it helps!
